# PAR::Packer install fails on Windows 7 32-bit with Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have Padre/DWIM Perl installed on Windows 7 32-bit, and I'm trying to install PAR::Packer so I can make a standalone application, but when I run `cpan -i PAR::Packer` I get this:

```
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.202)
Database was generated on Mon, 10 Feb 2014 04:19:03 GMT
Running install for module 'PAR::Packer'
Running make for R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.017.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.63)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.042)
Checksum for C:\Dwimperl\cpan\sources\authors\id\R\RS\RSCHUPP\PAR-Packer-1.017.t
ar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.80)
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4401)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.120351)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.57)

  CPAN.pm: Building R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.017.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Prototype mismatch: sub main::prompt: none vs ($;$) at C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib/ExtU
tils/MakeMaker.pm line 219
Writing Makefile for par.exe
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing Makefile for PAR::Packer
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/App/Packer/PAR.pm blib\lib\App\Packer\PAR.pm
cp lib/PAR/Packer.pm blib\lib\PAR\Packer.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Obfuscate.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Obfuscate.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/PodStrip.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\PodStrip.pm
cp lib/PAR/StrippedPARL/Base.pm blib\lib\PAR\StrippedPARL\Base.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/PatchContent.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\PatchContent.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Bytecode.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Bytecode.pm
cp lib/pp.pm blib\lib\pp.pm
cp lib/PAR/Filter/Bleach.pm blib\lib\PAR\Filter\Bleach.pm
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe par_pl2c.pl my_par_pl < ..\script\par.pl > my_par_
pl.c
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe sha1.c.PL
gcc -c -s -O2 -DWIN32  -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLIC
IT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields  -I"C:\Dwimpe
rl\perl\lib\CORE"  -DPARL_EXE=\"parl.exe\" -s -O2 main.c
In file included from main.c:3:0:
C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE/XSUB.h:520:0: warning: "fstat" redefined [enabled by d
efault]
 #    define fstat  PerlLIO_fstat
 ^
In file included from C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE/perl.h:1181:0,
                 from main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\sys\stat.h:301:0: note: this is the location of the previous de
finition
 #define fstat _fstat
 ^
In file included from main.c:3:0:
C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE/XSUB.h:531:0: warning: "stat" redefined [enabled by de
fault]
 #    define stat(buf,sb) PerlLIO_stat(buf,sb)
 ^
In file included from C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE/perl.h:1181:0,
                 from main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\sys\stat.h:300:0: note: this is the location of the previous de
finition
 #define stat _stat
 ^
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:121:23: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer targe
t type [enabled by default]
     fakeargv[argno++] = my_par_pl;
                       ^
windres -i winres/pp.rc -o ppresource.coff --input-format=rc --output-format=cof
f --target=pe-i386
g++ main.o ppresource.coff -s   -s -L"C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\Dwimperl\
c\lib"  C:\Dwimperl\perl\lib\CORE\libperl514.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\li
b\libmoldname.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libkernel32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i
686-w64-mingw32\lib\libuser32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a C:
\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinspool.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\li
b\libcomdlg32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libadvapi32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i
686-w64-mingw32\lib\libshell32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libole32.a C
:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\liboleaut32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\l
ib\libnetapi32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libuuid.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686
-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libmpr.a C:\Dwim
perl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinmm.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libver
sion.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbc32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-min
gw32\lib\libodbccp32.a C:\Dwimperl\c\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomctl32.a -o par.e
xe
rem
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe encode_append.pl Dynamic.in par.exe Dynamic.pm
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe file2c.pl -c 30000 par.exe C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\pe
rl514.dll C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll C:./Program > boot_embedded_f
iles.c
open input file 'C:./Program': No such file or directory at file2c.pl line 43.
dmake:  Error code 130, while making 'boot_embedded_files.c'
dmake:  'boot_embedded_files.c' removed.
dmake.EXE:  Error code 255, while making 'subdirs'
  RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.017.tar.gz
  C:\Dwimperl\c\bin\dmake.EXE -- NOT OK
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.77)
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

I don't know what to make of it, so I Googled various parts of it, but it seems like everyone who has an issue with installing this module has it for a different reason.

Previously I had installed Padre with Strawberry Perl and had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried install with "force"?

**"cpan force -i PAR::Packer"**

or into cpan client

**"force install PAR::Packer"**

Other think you should check is the permission os the user you'r using to run the exe file.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be problem in your file file2c.pl at line 43. If you fix it, you should be able to build par exe.

```
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe file2c.pl -c 30000 par.exe C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl514.dll C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll C:./Program > boot_embedded_files.c
open input file 'C:./Program': No such file or directory at file2c.pl line 43.
```